# how can I write a function in scala called Order that takes one arguement: a list of Ints. And returns the same List of Ints from least to greatest

Tags: scala

I've got a base case and a recursive call but I don't know where to go from there.I do also need to use pattern matching

```
def order(ls:List[Int]):List[Int] = ls match {
   case Nil => Nil
   case h::t => order(t)
```

Comment: I assume they wanted you to implement quick-sort-like solution, but without sorting (partition) in-place. But giving you the solution here would kind of defeat the purpose of the exercise.

Comment: can i get some help. i've thought of everything that doesn't work

Comment: Partition on list using pivot (head), merge sorted left side with sorted right side with pivot in the middle.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you are looking for a recursive sort algorithm.
You can take a look at merge sort for example. This is a simplified Non generic version

```
def mergeSort(ls: List[Int]): List[Int] = {
  def merge(l: List[Int], r: List[Int]): List[Int] = (l, r) match {
    case (Nil, _) => r
    case (_, Nil) => l
    case (lHead :: lTail, rHead :: rTail) =>
      if (lHead < rHead) {
        lHead :: merge(lTail, r)
      } else {
        rHead :: merge(l, rTail)
      }
  }

  val n = ls.length / 2
  if (n == 0)
    ls
  else {
    val (a, b) = ls splitAt n
    merge(mergeSort(a), mergeSort(b))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
def order(ls:List[Int]):List[Int] = ls match {
case Nil => Nil
case h => h.sorted
}

 OR

def order(ls:List[Int]):List[Int] = ls match {
case Nil => Nil
case h => h.sortWith(_ < _)
}
```